# Will iframed Facebook-Buttons quirk in IE6 by default?

Tags: facebook, iframe, styles

I've integrated this nice Facebook-Button to my WordPress site via iframe. Although I care for cross-browser-compatibility plus the fact I could not influence the iframe content in regular ways I'm wondering why this quirks when viewed in IE6.

Could I've done something wrong anyway or is it conceivable stuff quirks by default and Facebook doesn't care about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook does officially *not* support IE 6 any more.

(And I’m glad about that. Just wondering why *you* still care?)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Didn't read that anywhere unfortunately. On the one hand I agree with you - I'm also glad it's like that - We all hate IE6. But a reason for carrying for IE6 is, that I have to adress customers that are not very familiar with computers (for example theologists that feel bound to old books instead of any modern media :-)